# MAAS for diskless computational hpc cluster

Tags: cluster, deployment, hpc

I'm considering to use MAAS to deploy OS for a computational cluster. All nodes are diskless. Only head node and (probably) MAAS rack controller will have hard drives. It seems MAAS have to finish a node commissioning before using it, but how possible to commission a node without system installation?

After one day search no result, only clouds with Juju. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's HPC system provisioners that will achieve what you want. Which is running stateless compute nodes from RAM. And it's recommended to use them because they are designed to provide the required resources for HPC systems.

I would recommend picking up any of the following:

- xCAT: http://xcat.org
- Warewulf: https://warewulf.lbl.gov
- Bright Computing Easy8: https://www.brightcomputing.com/easy8

All of them are free, except Easy8, that is free up to 8 compute nodes. It's a proprietary software. Personally I would go for xCAT.